# mysqli_affected_rows, mysql subtract 2 columns error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a column I want to update with results of the difference between 2 mysql columns and count how many rows were affected. In my case it can only be 1. This is the mysql query I am using which is not consistent at all

```
$connection->query("UPDATE items SET Quantity_Available = Quantity - Quantity_Committed WHERE Item_ID = '$itemid'");
if($count=$connection->affected_rows!=1){echo $count;die('makassi');}
```

If I replace the Quantity_Committed with a numeric value, I get what I want i.e the code continues. However if I leave it as it is, I get the proper $count figure(1) but it also fails by echoing 'makassi' which it shouldn't.

Is this an improper way of subtracting 2 mysql columns or is this a bug in the php mysqli api?? 
This is really baffling to me!! Help please

Comment: Run the query using phpmyadmin, or what you are familier with.

Comment: why you would require "Quantity_Available" column separately. You can use **(Quantity - Quantity_Committed) as Quantity_Available**.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk, that is what i am trying to say since the begining.

Comment: @Max, I recreated your scenario, and tested using phpmyadmin, and your same syntax and its is working fine. As I have mentioned in my comments, please post your schema and few datas, you are working with.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Yeah just realized so too. That column was useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad practice what you are trying to do. If a column in the database is derived from another column already in the column. Then such is create redundancy is the database. All a database should be normalized as much as possible. Please read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) about data normalization.

Whatever you are trying to do can be achieved in a much better way. Like

Filtering the records

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE Quantity - Quantity_Column > 5
```

Or, retrieving the quantity available.

```
SELECT (Quantify - Quantity_Column) as `Quality_Available` from items
```

Comment: Really, a field in your table is derived from two other fields, and you are telling me that the table data is not redundant. And `It just so happens that 1 field(quantity_available) is affected by the subtraction of 2(quantity-quantity_committed) fields.` and you are wondering where in your question, I got the impressions of ????

Comment: He wants to update column from another two columns and what are you trying to speak are both irrelevant. Is there any relation with question?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk, Yes there is, the question arises because it is following bad practices. I am not answering what OP has asked, because this question should not exist in the first place.

Comment: Just read the rest of your answer before making my previous comment. The problem is if i comment the IF statement(I don't do the count validation) the query is successful. Only one item quantity is updated and with the correct values e.t.c. This result must be stored into a field. I don't see how a SELECT statement will help me update the table unless I use it together with an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Max, If you really want to go your way, please provide the schema of your table and some sample data as well.

Comment: @Starx You are absolutely right. This is indeed bad practice. Took a long hard look at my php code and my database shema and made some necessary changes. Deleted some php code and a column. Thanks dude. I think the reason I put the quantity available field is so that my PHP application could just read directly from the db how many items are available(I'm making an e-commerce website). now I just have to make the subtraction as you illustrated but in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: @Max, Glad I could help. :) Best of luck for the website.